# Are there any existing tools to convert c++ header files to header + implementation?

Tags: c++, header-files

I tend to prototype C++ classes as a self-contained class, i.e. like:

```
class BlahBlahBlah
{
public:
  void SomeMethod()
  {
    // some code here
  }
};
```

and then later when I am happy with the design I will turn it into a .h/.cpp pair. This is mostly a mechanical task so is there any tool out there that can help with that?

Comment: The decision which functions should be implemented inline in the class definition and which not should be a conscious decision, driven by several factors. The are different camps in the C++ community when it comes to prioritizing these factors. How do you think a tool should do that?

Comment: @sbi That's why I said /mostly/ mechanical. I expect to do some tweaking afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Lzz](http://www.lazycplusplus.com/).

Comment: Nice tool but unfortunately it is almost too clever. It has a full parser and so all comments get removed. It also re-orders some constructs (e.g. const &) which would require another smart parser to put back.

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) has [a refactor tool that does this](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/moveImplementation.asp). You can bind it to a keyboard shortcut so you can do it case-by-case, rather than robotically.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Lzz you might consider taking a look at [Preprocess - A preprocessor for C and C++ modules](http://os.inf.tu-dresden.de/~hohmuth/prj/preprocess/). Unlike Lzz, it does preserve comments. However, it does have some limitations. It does not support namespaces or nested classes. But since it's written in PERL and I imagine it would not be too difficult to extend and customize.

There is also [inlsplit: Inline C++ Source and Header splitter](http://somewhere.fscked.org/proj/inlsplit/). It is a very simple awk script which parses a single .inl file and places all member functions with a @ folowing their prototype into the source file, keeping only the declaration in the header. There is also a @source tag for code to go straight into the implementation. Compared to lzz and preprocess, it is very lightweight. However it has been abandoned and there is no new development.